# Multithreading and pthread_join

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthread-join

My program reads in maze from a text file, then the main program creates 3 different threads to delve into this maze and search for the exit. When a thread discovers the exit, it will post its solution path in the main thread.

In this maze, there are pitfalls, which when a thread encounters, will "die", saving the location of that pitfall to a global array of discovered pitfall points, so that the other threads would know where to avoid. After that thread dies, the main program will respawn another thread to take its place and continue traversing the maze.

A thread may or may not encounter encounter a pitfall, and using pthread_join only waits for a specific thread. How do I make the main thread to wait for each of the threads simultaneously?

Comment: What about you join only threads that have singalled in some way they are ready? Like setting a flag somewhere?

Comment: My threads are stored in an array of pthread_t, so could I use a global integer to do it?
Like this:
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
while(!foundSolution)
{
   pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
   pthread_create(threads[exited], NULL, thrd_func, &pathfinder[exited]);
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a condition variable which in pthreads is `pthread_cond_t`.  Have the main thread wait on the condition variable, and right before a thread dies have it signal the condition variable.  In pseudo code something like this:

**main thread**

```
//spawn first set of threads
while(!done) {
   pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
   //spawn another thread
}
```

**worker thread**

```
//traverse maze
pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond);
//thread exit
```

Note that when using a condition variable you need to acquire and release an associated mutex.  Look at the man page for `pthread_cond_wait` for more details.

Comment: One question I want to ask, for the worker thread, do I unlock the mutex before signal broadcast or after(before exiting)?

Comment: you should unlock the mutex after doing the signal broadcast.